# Pick out of N tuples to find all possible combinations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am trying to figure out a solution for a problem. Consider the following tuples (it could be any number of tuples, I am using four in this example):

1. $\{A, B, C, D\}$
2. $\{E, F, G, H\}$
3. $\{I, J, K, L\}$
4. $\{M, N, O, P\}$

Out of this tuples I have to construct a four-character string, but I can only choose one element from each tuple. Note that if I had $N$ tuples, it would be an $N$-character string.

The strings "AEIM", "BGLP", "DEIO" are valid examples. The string "EAIM" is not, because the 'A' and 'E' are in the wrong position.

Since I am choosing one letter from each tuple, I think this involves some form of permutation/combination. However, I cannot see beyond this.

Any form of help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jvdhooft!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would help you to think of it as a tree (or trees). Start from a character from the first tuple then add all possible second characters from the second tuple, etc...

Comment: Hmm nice suggestion. I actually can see how that helps, I will do this!

Answer (score 1):

If the $i^{th}$ tuple contains $c_i$ characters, there are $c_i$ ways to choose the $i^{th}$ character in the string. Choosing a character for every tuple, the number of possible combinations equals:

$$c_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot c_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n}c_i$$

In your example, $c_i=4$ for each tuple $i$. As such, the number of possible words equals:

$$4^4 = 256$$